# How to pass information from one method to another in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, metadata

I am web scraping data from a website that requires me to get the data from the individual candidate profiles. The catch is, a part of data is to be extracted from the profile snippet and the rest of it has to be extracted after entering the profile.

The fields which are to be extracted using snippet are:
1. Work Authorization
2. Candidate Name
3. Image ID

Rest of the data can be extracted once the profile is opened.

The Issue:

I have written a spider and want to pass on the data of the above-mentioned fields from one method to another. Now, when I crawl my spider, I get the data of these three fields repeated for all the candidate profiles on a particular page. I am actually new to web scraping and python. Can you please help me?

I am attaching my spider code and items.py file for reference:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from hbs_candidates.items import HbsCandidatesItem

domain = 'https://www.myvisajobs.com'
url = 'https://www.myvisajobs.com/CV/Search.aspx?DG=Bachelor&P=1'
page_scraped = 2
classes = ['HighLight: ', 'Membership: ', 'Honor: ', 'Skills: ', 'Degree: ', 'Career Level: ', 'Certification: ','Occupation: ', 'Reference: ', 'Target Locations: ', 'Career Title: ', 'Goal: ', 'Target Title:']


class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'inform'
    start_urls = [url]
    # page_no = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        wa_temp = []
        items = HbsCandidatesItem()
        tables = response.xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_divContent"]/center/table/tr""")
        names_temp = tables.css('b a::text').extract()
        images_temp = [domain + x for x in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract()[1:]]
        for i in range(len(tables)):
            wa = str(tables.xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_divContent"]/center/table/tr[3]/td[2]/text()[6]""").extract()).split('Work Authorization: ')[1]
            if wa is not None:
                temp_wa = wa
            else:
                temp_wa = 'N/A'
            wa_temp.append(temp_wa)
        my_list = response.css('b a::attr(href)').extract()
        for i in range(len(my_list)):
            url_final = urljoin(url, my_list[i])
            temp_url = response.urljoin(url_final)
            items['Candidate Name'] = names_temp[i]
            items['Image ID'] = images_temp[i]
            items['Work Authorization'] = wa_temp[i]
            request = scrapy.Request(temp_url, callback=self.parse_can_contents)
            request.cb_kwargs['items'] = items
            yield request

    def parse_can_contents(self, response, items):
        ### code to scrape data from profile page and assigning values to 
        items
        -----------
        -------------

        ## I want to access the values passed from parse method here    
        yield items
```

The items.py code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class HbsCandidatesItem(Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.fields:
            self.fields[key] = Field()
        self._values[key] = value
```

I hope this is clear. Please ask if the question seems ambiguous. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items (items = HbsCandidatesItem()) should be created inside the for loop

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
        url_final = urljoin(url, my_list[i])
        temp_url = response.urljoin(url_final)
        items = HbsCandidatesItem()
        items['Candidate Name'] = names_temp[i]
        items['Image ID'] = images_temp[i]
        items['Work Authorization'] = wa_temp[i]
        request = scrapy.Request(temp_url, callback=self.parse_can_contents)
        request.cb_kwargs['items'] = items
        yield request
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Can you explain why items should be inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, because you created the items object outside the for loop, and on every loop, you assign a value to the same key. For example the value for the key 'Candidate Name' is always being replaced in the same object on every iteration of the loop, and this way you end up with the last value for all the records you "scraped". If the item object is created inside the loop its values are not replaced in the next iteration, because it is a new object every time. If you are happy with the solution can you mark it as correct, please ;)